# Can't remove ActionBr in android studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

So i've been trying to remove the Action bar in my layout but failed. I tried to insert `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"` in the Manifest activity but it did not work and gave me the error `Cannot resolve symbol "@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"`.

my Manifest.XML layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bassammetwally.newer">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.bassammetwally.newer.MainActivity">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by adding following code to your base theme.

```
 <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

My code in which I am removing actionbar.

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Still not working. The ActionBar is now white and still has the title.

Comment: have you removed android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" from manifest?

Comment: Yes i did. still the same

Comment: You have also used android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar in your xml also in RelativeLayout. Try by removing it

Comment: Yeah i removed it from my RelativeLayout and Manifest and i added windowNoTitle and false windowActionBar and still its showing the action bar but white.

Answer (score 0):

Use,

```
 getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

in your java file.